# Flash AS3 LoaderMax Resizing Issue - How to keep the same scale mode on stage resize

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, loader

I'm using the loadermax class from greensock in order to load an image which matches the screen's width and height, using a scaleMode of proportionalOutside. The problem is, if I resize the stage, the image does not scale with it. Is there a way to resize the image while maintaining loaderMax's scaleMode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I used to scale this proportionally:

```
var contentWidth = stage.stageWidth / stage.stageHeight; //used for tracking aspect ratio on fs media
var contentHeight = stage.stageHeight / stage.stageWidth; //used for tracking aspect ratio on fs media


if ((stage.stageHeight / stage.stageWidth) < contentHeight) {
     fsMedia.fsContainer.width = stage.stageWidth;
     fsMedia.fsContainer.height = contentHeight * fsMedia.width;
} else {
     fsMedia.fsContainer.height = stage.stageHeight;
     fsMedia.fsContainer.width = contentWidth * fsMedia.height;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to do the calculations yourself. If your matching the stage size it should be pretty simple:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
function stageResizeHandler(event:Event):void {
  loader.width = stage.stageWidth;
  loader.height = stage.stageHeight;
}
function loaderCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
  stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, stageResizeHandler);
}
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler);
this.addChild(loader);
```

You'll likely have to finagle that code a little depending on your setup, but I (or someone on sof) can help you through it if you get stuck.

Comment: yeah - I ended up having to do the calculations myself. Below's the code I used to scale proportionally.